# Hatcher last part of Example 3.11

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's Example 3.11 he proves that $H^n(Y, R) \to H^{n+1}(I\times Y, \partial I\times Y; R), \beta\mapsto \alpha \times \beta$ is an isomorphism for $\alpha$ a generator of $H^1(I, \partial I; R)$ and $Y$ any space. Now the part I don't understand is the following:

Why is this equivalent to $H^n(Y,R)\to H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y, \{s_0\}\times Y; R), \beta \mapsto \alpha \times \beta$ being an isomorphism for $\alpha $ a generator of $H^{1}(S^1, s_0; R)$. Does the map $ (I \times Y, \partial I \times Y)\to (S^1\times I, \{s_0\}\times Y)$ induces an isomorphism on cohomology of pairs, if so, why?

I also don't understand the following claim: He says that the long exact sequence of the pair $(S^1\times Y, \{s_0\}\times Y)$ given by $$\dots\to H^n(S^1\times Y; R)\to H^n(\{s_0\}\times Y; R) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y, \{s_0\}\times Y; R)\to H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y; R)\to H^{n+1}(\{s_0\}\times Y;R)\to\dots$$ would imply that the map $H^{n+1}(Y;R)\times H^n(Y;R)\to H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y; R), (\beta_1, \beta_2)\mapsto 1\times \beta_1 + \alpha \times\beta_2$ would be an isomorphism. Are the boundary maps in that sequence zero maps and the other part is split?

Thank you for your help.

This refers to the version of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology from 2002.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The quotient maps induce an isomorphism $I \times Y/(\partial I \times Y) \to S^1\times Y /(\{s_0\}\times Y)$ and so the quotient maps give isomorphisms (the coefficient ring $R$ committed)
$$\overline{H}^n(S^1\times Y /(\{s_0\}\times Y))\to \overline{H}^n(I \times Y/(\partial I \times Y))$$ and these are by exision (these are good pairs),as in the homology case, isomorphic to $H^n(S^1\times Y ,\{s_0\}\times Y)$ and $H^n(I\times Y , \partial I \times Y)$ respectively.

Hence, $H^n(Y)\to H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y, \{s_0\}\times Y), \beta \mapsto \alpha \times \beta$ is an isomorphism as it is the composition of the already proven isomorphism $H^n(Y, R)\to H^{n+1}(I\times Y, \partial I \times Y)$ and the isomorphism $H^n(I\times Y , \partial I \times Y)\to H^n(S^1\times Y ,\{s_0\}\times Y)$ induced by the quotient map $(I\times Y ,\partial I \times Y)\to (S^1\times Y ,\{s_0\}\times Y)$.

The sequence associated to the pair $(S^1\times Y , \{s_0\}\times I) $ is split, since the inclusion $i: \{s_0\}\times  Y \hookrightarrow S^1\times Y$ has a retraction given by the projection on the $Y$-coordinate $p_2: S^1\times Y\to Y\to \{s_0\}\times Y$.

Hence, the sequence associated to $(S^1\times Y , \{s_0\}\times I) $ is a concatenation of split exact for each $n$ given by
$$0 \to H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y, \{s_0\}\times Y)\to H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y) \xrightarrow{i^*} H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y) \xrightarrow{i^*} H^{n+1}(\{s_0\} \times Y )\to 0.$$

We conclude that the map
$$H^{n+1}(Y)\oplus H^n(Y)\to H^{n+1}(Y)\oplus H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y, \{s_0\}\times Y)\to H^{n+1}(S^1\times Y), \\(\beta_1,\beta_2)\mapsto (\alpha\times \beta_1, \beta_2)\mapsto \alpha\times \beta_1 + p_2^*(\beta_2)=\alpha\times \beta_1+1\times \beta_2$$ is an isomorphism.

This (if it is correct) answers the questions I had.